# Get second line of output from command

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files with the `json` extension in a directory. These are used to generate some other files but that should only happen if the `json` files have changed.

So far I have the following measly script:

```
for %%f in (*.json) do (
            echo %%f
            certutil -hashfile %%f SHA256 >> HASH.txt
    )
```

I loop through all the `json` files, generate the SHA256 hash value for each and then append it to the `HASH.txt` file using `certUitl`. My problem comes from the output that tool returns namely (I have a German Win 10):

```
SHA256-Hash der Datei BLAH.json:
d8338f6f2649bcb358e56e0973fe2f5a886771e0debbdb0fefef35976a1b88ca
CertUtil: -hashfile-Befehl wurde erfolgreich ausgeführt.
```

I'd like to get my hands on the hash value. With the example above that would be

```
d8338f6f2649bcb358e56e0973fe2f5a886771e0debbdb0fefef35976a1b88ca
```

which is the second line of the output. I've searched for a solution how to get only a specific line of the output and skip the rest but all I can find was related to text files which doesn't seem to help much. Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Sounds like a job for [findstr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb490907.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make your life easier when filtering certutil output with a
`findstr /V ":"`
the hash is the only line without a colon.

```
@Echo off
(for %%f in (*.json) do certutil -hashfile "%%~f" SHA256 | findstr /V ":" 
)> HASH.txt
```

A different approach gettting any specified line number:

```
@Echo off
Set Line=2
(for %%f in (*.json) do for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in (
  'certutil -hashfile "%%~f" SHA256 ^| findstr /n "^" ^|findstr "^%Line%:"'
) Do echo %%B) > HASH.txt
```

**Another variant storing hash and full file name in `HASHjson.txt`**

```
@Echo off
Set "Hash=HASHjson.txt"
For %%F in (*.json) do For /f %%A in (
    'certutil -hashfile "%%~F" SHA256 ^| findstr /V ":"'
) Do Findstr "^%%A" "%HASH%" >NUL 2>&1 && (
    Echo HASH %%A already present in %Hash%
) || (
    Echo Add %%A %%~fF
    >>"%Hash%" Echo %%A %%~fF
)
```

Sample run:

```
> hashjson.cmd
Add eaf7df6fd6fe0719b6eafef8e4f74070684125822d03e6642a7e42fb425b442b A:\AIMavJ5IlpEmYCN.json
Add 24f1508e5e4a920b3233a37ce959e1e4f3fcd2a4ed90daec7879bc58af2a3a98 A:\AQ0G8KFw6KIj0JR.json

> hashjson.cmd
HASH eaf7df6fd6fe0719b6eafef8e4f74070684125822d03e6642a7e42fb425b442b already present in HASHjson.txt
HASH 24f1508e5e4a920b3233a37ce959e1e4f3fcd2a4ed90daec7879bc58af2a3a98 already present in HASHjson.txt
```

Comment: The one-line solution doesn't allow any further customization of what's appended to the file. I thought my situation through again and it seems that also storing the file name (something like `<filename>.json : <hash-value>`) would be nice since I will be able to later on check if the prefix (the `<filename>.json`) from each line in the text file actually exists as a file on the filesystem and THEN recalculate its hash value. Especially with many files this seems to be a faster approach instead of blindly "hashing" all files every time. Storing the output in a variable is better in this case.

Comment: Added a variant storing hash and file name check if hash already present.

Comment: I'll adapt this (so that it's the filename that is compared and not the hash) but still a bit thank you. Really helpful. And you do like one-liners, I can tell. :D

Answer (score 1):

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38772234/1559401) I got my wish:

```
for %%f in (*.json) do (
    echo %%f
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set /a count=1 
    for /f "skip=1 delims=:" %%a in ('CertUtil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256') do (
      if !count! equ 1 (
        echo %%a >> HASH.txt
      )
      set/a count+=1
    )
    endlocal
)
```

The script outputs a file `HASH.txt` with the content:

> 227041a0fb9086c047692b5fc5e96437abe7a2664cc7e2dbcaa0bbe9c89cd886 
>   bf4cf9401299ee68d24c88d1ff93152d4333956c58b305144b6469d86a8a803f 
>   7b64b046d6121d9ef7db9e8f4a46b11b583a2c294501cf805120982d1a3b4b4c 
>   b5ff9fcd040d55ba77a75578d8bee5d26382d3ba952c38952fefcbe08cc10b9f 
>   a78294c3e0d7e6311ada02da35ea25240edc7b0f7c2e601e9840162e5fb5228c 
>   f3b21270b95d514e24a68658c77718cbe827487cdc32b46864a67172ae0afebc 
>   0affcf4c3ba645c7aff44cfcb08fabd8769e84042b935907199d031601bf8e6a 
>   3c197b9b991c6e9d66db0fee74d2fe2ea332e7f649459b08d89ba34e89ae9d27 
>   5d676c597f4839bf05feace8d02fa1ec6e4c08d8b5f75266c0237cdd816f838b 
>   323fc8da682b19aa11c250dd5129c7a581572e82ad88fb9c52f8c0679d7b8c12 
>   49ec95e5b45c74638e035a37983de74da91d4aea78d35abe749ce9d5556c1c5d 
>   84f1b5865d7949127bcc4a64e664ea75422cf4364c3e4acc2989e991cd6d0056 
>   588f1173ac020b589a632d2d6dba61958243d78efe10afd2bb21cc49a33a146a 
>   6a9e8887d25f5719568bf5321845d90afc800457947c3522f76717e469e3acea 
>   2d4800aa9c58c477f4bfeab47a98bc35aab8446a53453a43ed40a553066549c9 
>   f5e307075774bfa0eb9b65891c428799658d36e1b42be28cba67a920069a2c21 
>   ad755392444209412dc49d172603c4f7fa693589a0390ae626470f96d8ebb22b 
>   8ac329790c5df762bfb5d3437b2470fcd238b426ad60541ae89394f2620d867c 
>   cb6e4239db4cf53e236dcea70c245f053b636b70830d3f80946433f702049b95 
>   0403ab147b4d4788ce84df45c52c33e004cbdf9c77ad14a7b844e56b18bf9d00 
>   b9459119c08710713f5fb5816446149bf1314b34aa359c7ef35c12c1bf40ef27 
>   235bd76cf4c4684714ec42847a1bd0a673eb07f5ee19c9bc86ce6f1a9d24449e 
>   082cb0bee5ef63ec6c6ed5307000af5c89af2e75c6f9abdad9d3fafe37a725bf 
>   3af4b54bd63686df3175cf9e2d4f24bb4600385230b86f8342efa9a039f31c3c 
>   96ca349e805dae74aabb8252d2c4ffdabe17cabe0421742e1d12e672070f06b5 
>   d8338f6f2649bcb358e56e0973fe2f5a886771e0debbdb0fefef35976a1b88ca

Basically the output from `certUtil` is treated like the content of a text file allowing the use of `skip`, `delim` etc.

Comment: You could make your life easier when filtering certutil output with a `findstr /V ":"` the hash is the only line without a colon. So you could replace the whole inner for with `CertUtil -hashfile "%%f" SHA256 | findstr /V ":" >> HASH.txt`

Comment: Can you post this as the answer. It's much shorter and elegant than what I currently have. :D

Answer (score 1):

To speed it up, use a filter instead of looping:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist hash.txt del hash.txt

for %%f in (*.json) do (
   for /f "delims=" %%_ in ('certutil -hashfile %%f SHA256 ^| find /v ":"') do (
      set x=%%_
      set x=!x: =!
   )
   echo !x! >> hash.txt
)
```

The second line in the innermost block (second `for` is not a loop!) discards the blanks in the hash value.
`endlocal` is implicit with the end of the batchfile.

Answer (score 1):

If I can answer with unix command (Microsoft annouce it will embed all unix utility program inside Windows 10 update and new release) :

- sed -n "3p" "C:\Temp\my_file.txt" (output line 3 of file or StdIn)

Otherwise, it is quite easy to 'copy/paste' old unix faitfull program compile for Windows to do the job quite easy :

- http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/picnix/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/
- https://sourceforge.net/projects/gnuwin32/

For before this Windows 10 update, you can use :

- type "C:\Temp\my_file.txt" | findstr /n . | findstr /b ^3: (this will output line 3 of the file, but the line number will have to be strip out)